# Limit text to allowed characters only - (not by enumerating the wrong characters) | VBA

Tags: string, vba, validation

I would like to limit certain textboxes to accept only [A-Za-z]
I hope, a counterpart to Like exists.
With Like I would have to make a long list of not allowed characters to be able to filter.

```
Not MyString like [?;!°%/=....]
```

I can think of a solution in the form of:

```
For Counter = 1 To Len(MyString)
    if Mid(MyString, Counter, 1) Like "*[a-z]*" = false then
        MsgBox "String contains bad characters"
        exit sub
    end if
next
```

**... but is there a more sophisticated 1liner solution ?**

Until then, I have created a function to make it "Oneliner":

```
Function isPureString(myText As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    isPureString = True
    For i = 1 To Len(myText)
        If Mid(myText, i, 1) Like "*[a-zA-Z_íéáűúőöüóÓÜÖÚŐŰÁÉÍ]*" = False Then
            isPureString = False
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

If i add 1 more parameter, its also possible to define the allowed characters upon calling the function.

Comment: RegExp can be used.

Comment: Yes, and thanks for the tip, but that would involve an even more complex code. Starting with the object creation: CreateObject("vbscript.regexp"). So there is no inbuilt, fancy oneliner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633517/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters

Comment: No fancy one liner. Using the API call for [IsCharAlpha](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646979(v=vs.85).aspx)  will likely be more efficient when iterating and exiting at first false e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93105/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-character-is-a-letter-in-vb6

Comment: Thanks guys, i totally accept this:  `IsAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", Len(strValue))` as a oneliner. I accept it as a solution, especially as it does not require external stuff.

Comment: use `If text Like "*[!A-Za-z]"` to test if a string has some characters not in range `A-Za-z`.

Comment: Needs an extra * to work properly, like `"*[!A-Za-z]*"` ; but otherwise YES, that "!" is the simplest expression i was hoping to logically exist in the first place. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems my question was a bit of a duplicate, even though that did not pop in my search results.
So credits for @QHarr   for posting the link.

The solution I can forge from that idea for my "oneliner" is:

```
If myText Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", Len(myText))=false then 'do something.
```

Using .rept is inspiringly clever and elegant in my oppinion.
So what is does: Multiplies the search criteria for each charater instead of looping through the characters.

**EDIT:**
In an overaboundance of nice and elegant solutions, the most recent leader is:

```
If not myText Like "*[!A-Za-z]*" then '... do something
```

**Statistics update:**
I have tested the last 3 solutions' performance:
I have pasted @ in the below text strin at the beginning, at the end or nowhere.
The criteria were: `"*[a-zA-Z \S.,]*"` 
For 100000 repetitions

```
text = "This will be a very Long text, with one unwanted in the middle, to be able to test the difference in performance of the approaches."
```

1.) Using the [!...]  -> **30ms** with error, **80ms** if no error 
2.) Using .Rept   -> around **1800ms** for all cases 
3.) Using characterLoop+Mid -> around **3000ms** if no error / **40-80ms** ms if early error

---