# How to simulate C# char.IsLetter in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am not so happy with MSDN about char.IsLetter description. I can't understand so well. 
From common sense, the Letter is :A-Z,a-z,Unicode string... From what I test, "~!@#$%^..." and 0-9 are not belong to IsLetter category. Yeah, the range is huge, How to simulate C# char.IsLetter (write similar code) in VB6?

Comment: If you know that the char will be in ascii for sure you can do something like if((char >= 97 && char <= 122) || (char >= 64 && char <= 90)) return true; else return false;

Comment: or of course you can check the appropriate one for unicode :)

Comment: The problem is that all Unicode Strings also turn True. For example, Unicode #6211 is Letter. Since Unciode is a complicated thing, how to do?

Comment: A-Z,a-z,Unicode string<-Oh ok I thought u were only interessed in the A-Z,lower and upper letters. If you need all unicode letters I have no answer unfortunetly.

Comment: I can't understand MSDN description about IsLetter. If talking about Unicode, I can check the string whether it is Unicode,If so,Can I consider it is Letter？Public Function isUnicode(ByVal s As String) As Boolean

Comment: No because not all characters in unicode are letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function IsCharAlphaW Lib "user32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Function IsCharAlphaNumericW Lib "user32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Long

Public Property Get IsAlpha(character As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = IsCharAlphaW(AscW(character))
End Property

Public Property Get IsAlphaNumeric(character As String) As Boolean
    IsAlphaNumeric = IsCharAlphaNumericW(AscW(character))
End Property

Public Property Get IsNumeric(character As String) As Boolean
    IsNumeric = IsAlphaNumeric(character) And Not IsAlpha(character)
End Property

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Debug.Print "a", IsAlpha("a")
   Debug.Print "Z", IsAlpha("Z")
   Debug.Print "0", IsAlpha("0"), IsNumeric("0")
   Debug.Print "ChrW$(&HFF21)", IsAlpha(ChrW$(&HFF21))
   Debug.Print "ChrW$(&HFF10)", IsAlpha(ChrW$(&HFF10)), IsNumeric(ChrW$(&HFF10))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, but I did a VERY quick test. It uses the User32.dll API call **IsCharAlphaW** which should be available on Windows 2000 Professional and up. Try it out, and if it's not right I'll delete the answer so it doesn't confuse anyone.

Note: there is no error handling in the example.

```
Private Declare Function IsCharAlpha Lib "user32" Alias "IsCharAlphaW" (ByVal cChar As Long) As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    MsgBox "IsLetter(" & Text1.Text & ") = " & IsLetter(Left$(Text1.Text, 1))

End Sub

Private Function IsLetter(ByVal vCharacter As String) As Boolean

    IsLetter = IsCharAlpha(AscW(vCharacter))

End Function
```

Comment: OK, your solution is better. I got the similar answer from Dr.Unicode. Thank you and Dr.Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it, part of an answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62003)

```
Private Function IsLetter(ByVal character As String) As Boolean
    IsLetter = UCase$(character) <> LCase$(character)
End Function
```

Comment: From what I test,Unicode "我" (Unicode table #6211) is True.So UCase/LCase doesn't work.

Comment: This only works for languages using latin alphabets that have upper and lower case variants unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function IsCharAlphaW Lib "user32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Function IsCharAlphaNumericW Lib "user32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Long

Public Property Get IsAlpha(character As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = IsCharAlphaW(AscW(character))
End Property

Public Property Get IsAlphaNumeric(character As String) As Boolean
    IsAlphaNumeric = IsCharAlphaNumericW(AscW(character))
End Property

Public Property Get IsNumeric(character As String) As Boolean
    IsNumeric = IsAlphaNumeric(character) And Not IsAlpha(character)
End Property

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Debug.Print "a", IsAlpha("a")
   Debug.Print "Z", IsAlpha("Z")
   Debug.Print "0", IsAlpha("0"), IsNumeric("0")
   Debug.Print "ChrW$(&HFF21)", IsAlpha(ChrW$(&HFF21))
   Debug.Print "ChrW$(&HFF10)", IsAlpha(ChrW$(&HFF10)), IsNumeric(ChrW$(&HFF10))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This tells you what a character is according to the Unicode standard.

```
Public Const CT_CTYPE1 = &H1         '  ctype 1 information
Public Const CT_CTYPE2 = &H2         '  ctype 2 information
Public Const CT_CTYPE3 = &H4         '  ctype 3 information
Public Const C1_ALPHA = &H100   '  any letter
Public Const C1_BLANK = &H40    '  blank characters
Public Const C1_CNTRL = &H20    '  control characters
Public Const C1_DIGIT = &H4     '  decimal digits
Public Const C1_LOWER = &H2     '  lower case
Public Const C1_PUNCT = &H10    '  punctuation characters
Public Const C1_SPACE = &H8     '  spacing characters
Public Const C1_TRANSPARENT = &H1     '  new raster cap
Public Const C1_UPPER = &H1     '  upper case
Public Const C1_XDIGIT = &H80    '  hex digits
Public Const C1_DEFINED = &H200    '  Other defined char

Public Const C2_ARABICNUMBER = &H6     '  Arabic number
Public Const C2_BLOCKSEPARATOR = &H8     '  block separator
Public Const C2_COMMONSEPARATOR = &H7     '  common numeric separator
Public Const C2_EUROPENUMBER = &H3     '  European number, digit
Public Const C2_EUROPESEPARATOR = &H4     '  European numeric separator
Public Const C2_EUROPETERMINATOR = &H5     '  European numeric terminator
Public Const C2_LEFTTORIGHT = &H1     '  left to right
Public Const C2_NOTAPPLICABLE = &H0     '  no implicit directionality
Public Const C2_OTHERNEUTRAL = &HB     '  other neutrals
Public Const C2_RIGHTTOLEFT = &H2     '  right to left
Public Const C2_WHITESPACE = &HA     '  white space
Public Const C2_SEGMENTSEPARATOR = &H9     '  segment separator
Public Const C3_DIACRITIC = &H2     '  diacritic mark
Public Const C3_NONSPACING = &H1     '  nonspacing character
Public Const C3_NOTAPPLICABLE = &H0     '  ctype 3 is not applicable
Public Const C3_SYMBOL = &H8     '  symbols
Public Const C3_VOWELMARK = &H4     '  vowel mark

Function GetC1Type(B As String) As String
        Dim Ret As Long
        Dim A() As Integer
        ReDim A(1)
        A(0) = 0
        A(1) = 0
        Ret = GetStringTypeEx(&HB, CT_CTYPE1, B, -1, A(0))
        Dim Alpha As Long
        Dim Blank As Long
        Dim Cntrl As Long
        Dim Digit As Long
        Dim LowerC As Long
        Dim UpperC As Long
        Dim Punct As Long
        Dim SpaceChar As Long
        Dim HexDigit As Long
        Dim DefinedChar As Long
        Dim CharTypeString
        Dim X As Long
        Alpha = A(0) And C1_ALPHA
        Blank = A(0) And C1_BLANK
        Cntrl = A(0) And C1_CNTRL
        Digit = A(0) And C1_DIGIT
        LowerC = A(0) And C1_LOWER
        UpperC = A(0) And C1_UPPER
        Punct = A(0) And C1_PUNCT
        SpaceChar = A(0) And C1_SPACE
        HexDigit = A(0) And C1_XDIGIT
        DefinedChar = A(0) And C1_DEFINED
        If Alpha = C1_ALPHA Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Alpha "
        If Blank = C1_BLANK Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Blank "
        If Cntrl = C1_CNTRL Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Control "
        If Digit = C1_DIGIT Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Number "
        If LowerC = C1_LOWER Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Lower "
        If UpperC = C1_UPPER Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Upper "
        If Punct = C1_PUNCT Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Punct "
        If SpaceChar = C1_SPACE Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Space "
        If Len(CharTypeString) = 0 Then
            If DefinedChar = C1_DEFINED Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Other_Defined "
            If Len(CharTypeString) = 0 Then CharTypeString = CharTypeString & "Not_Defined "
        End If
        GetC1Type = CharTypeString
End Function
```

Comment: Very good code. I never knew this API. I will compare with C# char.IsLetter,IsDigit,IsNumber,IsControl,IsWhiteSpace,IsControl,IsLower,IsUpper. If you have more info about this comparison,please post this thread. Thank you,Sir.